# Chainlink API Get Request isn't returning a value

Tags: chainlink

I am creating the following Smart contract. It makes a Chainlink request which isn't returning a value from the API. I am using the following [jobID][1] and this [node][2], but the node doesn't start the job and I don't know why. I checked that the node has a balance of LINK tokens but it doesn't have any and I don't know how to send a balance to the contract node.

I am using Kovan Testnet to try the smart contract. Could you tell me something which I can try?

```
// This example code is designed to quickly deploy an example contract using Remix.

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink - 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e
     * Chainlink - 29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x56dd6586DB0D08c6Ce7B2f2805af28616E082455;
        jobId = "b6602d14e4734c49a5e1ce19d45a4632";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     ************************************************************************************
     *                                    STOP!                                         * 
     *         THIS FUNCTION WILL FAIL IF THIS CONTRACT DOES NOT OWN LINK               *
     *         ----------------------------------------------------------               *
     *         Learn how to obtain testnet LINK and fund this contract:                 *
     *         ------- https://docs.chain.link/docs/acquire-link --------               *
     *         ---- https://docs.chain.link/docs/fund-your-contract -----               *
     *                                                                                  *
     ************************************************************************************/
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //      {"ETH":
        //          {"USD":
        //              {
        //                  ...,
        //                  "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //                  ...
        //              }
        //          }
        //      }
        //  }
    
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        //request.add("path", "data.0.Myvalue");

        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        volume = _volume;
    }
    
    /**
     * Withdraw LINK from this contract
     * 
     * NOTE: DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION AS IT CAN BE CALLED BY ANY ADDRESS.
     * THIS IS PURELY FOR EXAMPLE PURPOSES ONLY.
     */
    function withdrawLink() external {
        LinkTokenInterface linkToken = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(linkToken.transfer(msg.sender, linkToken.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
    }
}
``


  [1]: https://market.link/jobs/0609deab-6d61-4937-85e4-a8e810b8b272/runs
  [2]: https://market.link/nodes/323602b9-3831-4f8d-a66b-3fb7531649eb/metrics?start=1631783169&end=1632387969
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Etherscan activity, it looks like the node you are using may be inactive. Try this node and jobId:

```
Oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8; 
JobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747";
```

These were taken from the [Chainlink Official Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/decentralized-oracles-ethereum-mainnet/).

To check to see if a node may be inactive or not, check out the oracle address in a block explorer. [You can see here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x56dd6586db0d08c6ce7b2f2805af28616e082455) that the original node you tried to use hasn't posted a transaction in quite a long time.

If a node is inactive you will need to find a new one or host one yourself. To find more nodes and jobs, you can check [market.link](https://market.link/) or use the one found in the docs as mentioned earlier.